# Latex book with specific font size

Tags: fontsize

I would like to have a latex book where the page size is 21cm x 21cm, with a 0.8cm margin.  And with a 13pt font.  Am using texmaker, which does not have any defined or user-defined templates for starting a basic document. Have also checked texstudio but although it has templates, they do not conform to the 21cm x 21cm page size, those predefined are too large for what I am doing.

I have coded the following, but cannot see a change in the font size.

```latex
      \documentclass[13pt]{book}   
        
     \usepackage{geometry}       
      \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm,
      right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm }
        
      \begin{document}
        
      hello world       
        
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, there is no 13pt option for the book class. Even the extsizes classes don't support 13pt, and as far as I can tell, even `\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont` doesn't work with Computer Modern, though it does work with other fonts, including Latin Modern. What fonts or font packages are you using? (The geometry package should be working though for the other stuff. Is it?)

Comment: Understood.  Have found memoir, which I can set to 14pt.

Comment: If you're flexible in document class, scrbook would support 13pt, if you wanted to go with that; use the option `fontsize=13pt`

Comment: Just curious: What's going on with the "paragraph separators" (U+2029   ) in your text? What editor introduces them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the font in standard CMR, with the `book.cls`, then try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}
        
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm,
      right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm }
\usepackage{type1cm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{16pt}
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\makeatother
      \begin{document}
\normalsize
        
      hello world
        
      \end{document}
```

Comment: It does work with book.  What are the meaning for `{13pt}{16pt}`?

Comment: It sets the font to 13pt with baselineskip of 16pt.

Comment: Are there any good rules on setting `\baselineskip` from the font size?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `fontsize` package, but you also need a fully scalable set of fonts.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for fully scalable Computer Modern fonts
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  paperheight=21cm,
  paperwidth=21cm,
  left=8mm,
  right=8mm,
  top=8mm,
  bottom=8mm,
}

\begin{document}

hello world

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Today I came to know about the package `fontsize.sty`... Thanks...

Comment: @MadyYuvi A friend of mine wrote it, I have to advertise. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Have found that the memoir document class allows font sizes past the 12pt. Thusly I started using

```
    \documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
```

Comment: With memoir it *is* possible to write a custom clo file and have it use that. Then one can have the exact font size setup one wants

Answer (score 0):

If you compile using `lualatex` (possibly `xetex` but not sure) you can use whatever font size, and line spacing, that you like. Even decimal numbers. Must be scalable fonts, of course: OpenType or TrueType. All text must be utf-8.

I already do this with my own document class. In order to load `fontspec`, the `\normalsize` must first be defined. That comes from the document class, or you can manually specify it in your own preamble (before loading `fontspec`).

Then, after `fontspec` loads, you can re-define `\normalsize` to suit yourself.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % Default font size. Process with lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{11.43pt}{15.824pt}}
\normalsize
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
Hello World.\\
Hello World\\
Hello World\par
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.723bp}{17.448bp}}
\normalsize
\makeatother
Hello Again\\
Hello Again\\
Hello Again\par
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result of code]

Keep in mind that some older TeX packages rely on having integer font size, Type 1 fonts, encodings that I never heard of, and so forth.