# Can I set the font to 14 pt in the octavo class?

Tags: fonts, octavo

I do not think an MWE is necessary for this question but here it is. You will see that the font reverses to the default 10pt to if I set it to 14pt. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[14pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
%layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
%layoutoffset={5mm, 10mm},
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2.5cm,
%marginparwidth=20pt,
    ]
    {geometry}  
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: `octavo` is based on the `book` class so uses default fonts, will see if there is another question on here that answers it or if it is specific to `octavo`. From the `octavo` documentation, p. 272:  "The size options are the standard 10pt,
11pt and 12pt, with the default size set to 10pt."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the solution by [@egreg last year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641742/273733) but as the `octavo` class is based on but not necessarily the same as the `book` class it is probably best to just post an answer. I tested it rather then flagging as duplicate as the `octavo` class might be different.

Using:

```
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}
```

Changes the font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{octavo}

\usepackage{fix-cm} % @egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641742/273733
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}

\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
%layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
%layoutoffset={5mm, 10mm},
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2.5cm,
%marginparwidth=20pt,
    ]
    {geometry}  
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works!