# Justification in paracol

Tags: paracol

I'm trying to typeset a cover using the package paracol. Please see the MWE and the pdf.
My problem is that I would like all the beginning of the lines to aligned on left side. I can obtain this only playing with horizontal spaces, but it is not elegant and also not perfect.

First question is: how can I justify?
Second question is: maybe there is a better way to have the typeset the same cover? Not using paracol but some other ways to precisely lay characters on the space of the page?

The hebrew letter is typeset with a particular type that you can download here (https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/fonts/ShlomoStam/ShlomoStam.zip), to obtain the same results. But I guess it is the same if you comment out the hebrew in my MWE?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2.5cm ]
    {geometry}

\usepackage{fix-cm} % @egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641742/273733
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage[italian]{varioref}

 \usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.05\textwidth
\columnratio{0.5}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}
\newfontfamily{\myfont}{Shlomo Stam}




\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{50pt}
%{\centering
   \noindent
   \hfill
  { \Huge Haim Ben-Abraham\\[4mm]}
  %}
  
  
   
   \begin{paracol}{2}
   \columnsep=0pt
   \noindent
   \vspace{37pt}
   
   {\fontsize{36pt}{27pt}\selectfont 
   %\color{red} 
   \hspace{10pt} \textbf{Settanta}\\[10mm]}
   
    
     \noindent
   \hspace{26pt} {\LARGE 
   %\color{red} 
    {Volti}}
   
      \vspace{7pt}
     \noindent
   \hspace{28pt} {\LARGE
   % \color{red} 
   {Passi}}
   
   \vspace{7pt}
       \noindent
   \hspace{28pt} {\LARGE 
   %\color{red} 
   {Gerusalemme}}
      \switchcolumn
 \noindent  {\fontsize{220pt}{1pt}\selectfont \vspace{-10pt} \hspace{-51pt} \myfont{ע}}


\end{paracol}
\vspace{36pt}
\noindent {\fontsize{40pt}{1pt}\selectfont   \hspace{25pt} \texthebrew{פנים רגלים ירושלים}}



\end{document}
```

Comment: It is just confused whether to write right-to-left or left-to-right.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this? Or should I leave paracol and do in another way?

Comment: I suspect this is more of a polyglossia than a paracol proglem..  First switch between right-to-left and left-to-right outside paracol., then do it inside.  It should be possible to do it sutomatically when you switch columns (see \definecolumnpreamble on page 14).